Trying to implement a typeclass for a function
I'm trying to implement a typeclass for a function type:
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module Match where

import Tokens (Token (..))

class Match a where
    match :: (Match b) => a -> [Token] -> Either String b

instance Match (Int -> b) where
    match = matchInt

matchInt :: (Match b) => (Int -> b) -> [Token] -> Either String b
matchInt fn (Number i : ts) = match (fn i) ts
matchInt _ _ = Left "missing integer argument"

I keep getting the following error at build time and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong:
error: [GHC-25897]
    • Couldn't match type ‘b1’ with ‘b’
      Expected: (Int -> b) -> [Token] -> Either String b1
        Actual: (Int -> b) -> [Token] -> Either String b
      ‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          match :: forall b1.
                   Match b1 =>
                   (Int -> b) -> [Token] -> Either String b1
        at src/Match.hs:11:5-9
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration
        at src/Match.hs:10:10-25
    • In the expression: matchInt
      In an equation for ‘match’: match = matchInt
      In the instance declaration for ‘Match (Int -> b)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        match :: (Int -> b) -> [Token] -> Either String b1
          (bound at src/Match.hs:11:5)
   |
11 |     match = matchInt
   |             ^^^^^^^^

I don't want to change the typeclass to refer explicitly to a function. That's because I want to be able to implement the typeclass for non-functions. (The idea is that you could pass a data constructor to match along with a list of tokens and it would spit out the fully constructed data or an error)
Update:
What I want to do is this. Let's say I have
data Foo = Baz Int Int

Now, I want to have
instance Match Foo where
  match foo _ = Right foo

So I could call
match Baz tokens

and it would extract the integers from the token list to construct Foo. (Of course, I want to do that for a lot more constructors that have a variety of parameters for where I would have to implement Match)

"you could pass a type constructor to match" You cannot. You pass values to functions, not types.

Hey, thanks. I made a mistake when I explained my question. I meant a data constructor.

A data constructor is a function.

Why are both a and b expected to implement Match?

Based on your matchInt function, you will only run the function once, and only for the first token.

My guess is that your class definition is wrong. Right now, it requires to be able to match any a in the class and produce Either String b for any b in the class. b is not constrained to be related to a in any way, match is required to work in all cases. Later, your matchInt instead requires that a = (Int -> b), so it only works in a particular case. You'd need to implement matchInt :: (Match b) => (Int -> c) -> [Token] -> Either String b instead to satisfy the requirements. But that can't work. Try to correct the class instead so that it actually requires what you intend.

Exactly what is the use of the a in a -> [Token] -> Either String b.
